# Baire one extension of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

I struggle with the following comment in Sierpinski's Hypothèse du continu, p. 49.

For every continuous function $f(x):X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there exist a Baire one function $g(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

What if both $X$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash X$ are dense and uncountable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be proved by the following:

For arbitrary $X\subset\mathbb{R}$, continuous $f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be extended to a function $F:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $F^{-1}(A)$ is a $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}$ for every closed $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ (a Lebesgue-one function such that $F|_X=f$).

Then the Lebesgue-Hausdorff theorem implies that the Lebesgue-one function $F$ is also Baire-one.

Comment: How do you get such $F$? Sorry for being slow, but I'm unfamiliar with this area and would like to know a little more. If you could point to a good source, that would be extra helpful.

Comment: I was able to recall the reference: Kuratowski, Topology, Volume 1, p445.